# How to retrieve table data contains special character without error by using cursor in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

There is a procedure stored in database which uses a cursor to retrieve name from a particular table.

Now problem is occurring when name contains special characters such as single quote ' or &.

Please remember I can not remove ' or & from the name, I need to copy as it is into other variable by using cursor.

Whenever these two types of name occur in table data the whole multithousand line package goes into error.

I can not change any other part of it, please suggest a way to retrieve the data without any error.

Comment: Can you clearly specify as a minimal example that what procedure, what cursor you have in order to make somebody would help you

Comment: This means your procedure is buggy. If you just read the name from a table and return that name, the characters cannot cause any error. It seems hence that at some point you use the name to build some SQL instruction from it and the special characters get in the way. So, look at your procedure, if you can find such code. The error message you get should tell you in which line the error occured. This may get you close to that point in code.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably help if you said which "error" you got. How does that piece of code (that fails) look like? Please, do not post 8000 lines!

Meanwhile, a suggestion or two:

- did you try to enclose those table names into **double quotes**? (By the way, who and why chose such "inventive" table names?)
- if you're running it in SQL*Plus or other tool that expects you to enter substitution variable's value (because that's how `&` is being interpreted), did you `SET DEFINE OFF` (or set any other appropriate setting)?

Comment: I don't think the OP meant that the name of the table had special characters.  But yes, I had to read it twice to see that.